# Angular build file naming without hashing

Tags: angular-cli

When I do normal build by:

> ng build

I get files:

```
Initial Chunk Files           | Names         |      Size    
main.67a03e810140e0bd.js      | main          | 132.08 kB    
polyfills.881fa69e872290d9.js | polyfills     |  36.19 kB    
runtime.3b2ac8c1adcf7f83.js   | runtime       |   1.04 kB
styles.ef46db3751d8e999.css   | styles        |   0 bytes
```

how to delete that ".67a03e810140e0bd." etc ?

PS. Its been made in .NET app if that matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `--output-hashing` option, so you would build using:

```
ng build --output-hashing=none
```

That being said, most times you actually want your file names to be hashed so your users' browsers don't use an old cached version of your files when you release a new version.